# Method not working on second time through: SVPullToRefresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, infinite-scroll

So, I've made some progress on my issue described here — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348458/svpulltorefresh-infinite-scroll-with-an-rss-feed

Nonetheless, I have a problem. The table loads 10 YouTube videos initially. Then, the second ten will load using

```
__weak MasterViewController *weakSelf = self;

[self.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{

    NSLog(@"Infinite Scroll");
    [weakSelf updateVideoList];

}];
```

-(void) updateVideoList essentially adds 10 items to the array that loads into the table view (reloadData is called on the tableview at the end after addObjectsFromArray adds items to the initial array). This works well enough. The problem is that trying to load a third 10 items does not work. I added the NSLog to see if it even goes into the method a second time, and it doesn't.

Is there any reason for the method to not work a second time?

**Edit** Here's updateVideoList, but I used the log to determine that the method isn't even called the second time through:

```
- (void) updateVideoList {

NSString *baseDomain = @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos";
NSString *maxresults = @"10";
NSString *startIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)videoList.count+1];
NSString *orderBy = @"published";
NSString *author = @"theverge";
NSString *extension = @"v=2&alt=jsonc";
NSString *urlYoutube = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?max-results=%@&start-index=%@&orderby=%@&author=%@&%@",
                        baseDomain,maxresults, startIndex,orderBy,author,extension];

NSDictionary *listOfVideos = [JSONParser listOfVideos:urlYoutube];
int videoListSize = [[[listOfVideos valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"totalItems"]  intValue];
if (videoListSize>0) {
    NSMutableArray *secondYoutubeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arrayVideoList = [[listOfVideos valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"items"];
    for (NSDictionary *videoDictionary in arrayVideoList) {
        NSString *idVideo = [videoDictionary valueForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *description = [videoDictionary valueForKey:@"description"];
        //NSString *updated = [videoDictionary valueForKey:@"updated"];

        //            NSString *departTimeDate = [videoDictionary valueForKey:@"updated"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
        //NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:departTimeDate];

        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSInteger day = [components day];
        NSInteger month = [components month];
        NSInteger year = [components year];

        NSString *updated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld, %ld, %ld", (long)month,(long)day,(long)year];

        NSString *duration = [videoDictionary valueForKey:@"duration"];

        NSString *title = [videoDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];

        // If we are using wifi, take hqDefault
        NSString *thumbnail = [[videoDictionary valueForKey:@"thumbnail"] valueForKey:@"hqDefault"];
        YoutubeVideo *video = [[YoutubeVideo alloc] initWithId:idVideo withDescription:description withUpdated:updated withDuration:duration withTitle:title withThumbnail:thumbnail];
        [secondYoutubeList addObject:video];

    }
    [videoList addObjectsFromArray:secondYoutubeList];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

Comment: That's not enough information to answer the question.  Show the code in `updateVideoList`.

Comment: Edited it. I tried to see if that method was even touched upon reaching the updated table view's bottom, but it wasn't.

Comment: Perhaps the code `SVPullToRefresh` code is broken, however calling `[UITableView reloadData]` has got to be a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting. If I don't call it, then the new information, though added to videoList, do not show up in the tableView

Comment: You still need to tell the tableview that there is new information,  and there are better ways than `reloadData`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. How would you go about it?

Answer (score 5):

You should call

[self.tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating];

Once your work of reloading is got completed.