# if (indexPath.row == [dataSource count]-1 creates unstable view

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have been trying to create a "Load More" option for my JSON feed. I have gotten it to work using the following method in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == [videoList count]-1)
{
    [self updateVideoList];
}
```

Update video list adds more items to the NSMutableArray that is my dataSource. Everything loads fine, but it is jarring, resulting in stuttering and lacking a UIActivityIndicator to prove that something is happening behind-the-scenes. How do I smooth this process out?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh). This is a third party library that I use to implement infinite scrolling, which is what it seems that you are trying to do.

Comment: I initially tried using SVPull to Refresh, but ran into issues — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358739/method-not-working-on-second-time-through-svpulltorefresh — Any suggestions?